# what should be put into the option default for the type array

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-5.3

I've started working with the type array of doctrine, but I got a problem with it when I tried to define a default value. I've put `array(un, deux, trois)` but this created it as it is in my postgresql db and not serialized as mentioned into the doc.

In the other hand, I don't think it's relevent to put the serialized value of my default value manually.

has anyone used this type before? anyhelp? thanks

Comment: Did you put quotes around 'un' 'deux' trois' ?

Comment: With this done, when running doctrine:schema:update a beautiful error shows up :/

Comment: Tell us more about the error pls

Comment: sure, here: `[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER numero SET  DEFAULT 'array('un', 'deux', 'trois')'':

  SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "un"
  LINE 1: ...y_table ALTER numero SET  DEFAULT 'array('un...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of the type array, initilization should be done into the constructor, not into the annotations